# In R, why is there <chr> in the first row when I read in the dataframe

Tags: r, tibble, readxl

After reading in data from excel, I checked the first five rows of the data. I realized there is `<chr>` at the first row. Anyone knows why? Also, why did it read in as a "tibble"?

This is the code I used to read in the data:

```
formulary_data <- read_xlsx('formulary.xlsx', 1)
```

[image]

Comment: What code are you using to read in the data.frame? Please provide code instead of pictures

Comment: This indicates that the column contains character values (strings). Printing tibbles always gives you the object class of the elements of columns in the second row.

Comment: @Martin Wettstein Thanks for your reply. So, will this affect my normal way of doing data manipulations?

Comment: It will not affect you at all, it's just a helpful note that is printed in your console. It won't change anything. (It also print `# A tibble: 6 x 7`. This is also a helpful note that won't change anything in your workflow.)

Comment: No, not at all. It's just something that's printed by default (pure cosmetics). It's not stored in the data and won't interfere with anything. The first data row is the third one displayed. The first are the names of the columns, the second one the type of their content, then your data begins.

Comment: I see. Thanks for both of your explanations. I am more familiar with Python and I'm just starting with R. In python first-row index starts with 0.

Comment: Please read the docs for this, too. From [`?read_xlsx`](https://readxl.tidyverse.org/reference/read_excel.html): *"Value: a tibble"*. If you are not familiar with what a tibble is, I suggest you read more from tidyverse.org, since that is one of its star "features".

Answer (score 2):

Tibbles from tidyverse contain the column type in view, it's not actually a row. See the note that your data is 6x7. If you want to change it to a data.table or data frame so the column type is not displayed, you can do the following:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(formulary_data)
head(formulary_data)
```

Or using base data.frame:

```
df_formulary_data <- as.data.frame(formulary_data)
head(df_formulary_data)
```